# How to print string from line php?

Tags: php

i need some help, please
i'm still newbie in php
i need how to sort a string from line in this structure, please

```
A: name pass { date=xx-xx-xxxx ; name=something ; email=xxx@xx.xx }
```

i need only to get the unknown date from this line
xx-xx-xxxx and decrease one day.
for example
29-12-2016, after decrease will be like that : 28-12-2016

original code :

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$email = "test@gmail.com"; 


while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);

     if (strpos($line, "$email") !== false)
        {
           $fdate = preg_match('/date=(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})/',$line , $date);
           $adate = date('d-m-Y', (strtotime($date[1]) - 86400));
           $data = explode(" ", $line);
           echo $adate ;
           echo "\n";
        }
}
fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried many options, i didn't get what i want
,very hard on me :(

Comment: @chris85, no mate, didn't try it, i'm newbie in php and i think this issue is advanced on my little experience :/

Comment: You being new makes 0 difference. If you tried something, post it and explain what specific part of that attempt is not working. Right now your question is just a begging for code.

Comment: @takendarkk i posted the whole code in my question

Comment: Now explain specifically how that code is not working. Expected results vs. Actual results.

Comment: @Moutamared what's the status here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$string = 'A: name pass { date=29-12-2016, ; name=something ; email=xxx@xx.xx }';
preg_match('/date=(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})/', $string, $date);
echo date('d-m-Y', (strtotime($date[1]) - 86400));
```

Output:

```
28-12-2016
```

This takes the date pulls it to a variable and then subtracts one day (86400 seconds).

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dK8aN1/1

Comment: The `$date` is populated from the `preg_match` it is an array containing the found string and the captured value. You want the captured value so index `1`. e.g. `$date[1]` Which is then passed to `strtotime` which converts the string to a unix timestamp which is the number of seconds between 1970 and today. The `date` functions takes unix timestamps and will convert them to requested format.

Comment: What happens currently? Error? No date echoed? 1970 date echoed? What is `$line`?

Comment: $line, is handle every line exist on the txt file, and the test is performed on line after line, to extract the date

Comment: yes, it's the right format, the variable hanlde a line from the file in this structure, as described on my quetsion
A: name pass { date=xx-xx-xxxx ; name=something ; email=xxx@xx.xx }

Comment: sorry it was my fault, it works mate,
one another question please, the results are sorted together in the same line, how to sort every date in new line ?

Comment: That code should be putting the date out on a new line in shell/command line. If you are in a browser use `<br>` in place of the `\n`. Please mark this as resolved if this solved your issue.

Comment: i was doing the same, but it was printing br on browser :)
,it's solved mate, thank you so much for your help
,i appreciate that